# MongoDB Aggregation: How to $match after a $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: `collA` and `collB` and I'm doing the following lookup:

```
db.collA.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {from: 'collB', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'key', as: 'bs'}
}])
```

If we stop here then `bs` is an array of objects

Every "b" object has a field `name`.

I'd like to filter only records where one of the `bs` answers the condition: `b.name == query_name`.

1. I think `$elemMatch` isn't possible
2. I also think I can `$unwind` and `$group` but it feels like an overhead.

Is there a simple way to filter by this condition?

**Sample Data:**

collA:

```
[
    {"_id": "1", "a": 1, "b": 1},
    {"_id": "2", "a": 2, "b": 2}
]
```

collB:

```
[
    {"key": "1", "name": "Ron"},
    {"key": "1", "name": "Bob"},
    {"key": "1", "name": "Dana"},
    {"key": "2", "name": "John"},
    {"key": "2", "name": "Ron"}
]
```

So if the query is `Ron` I'm expecting to get both documents from collA. If the query is `Bob` I'm expecting to get only the document with `_id == 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

Use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in `$project` stage to filter the document(s) from the array (`bs`).

```
db.collA.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collB",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "refId",
      as: "bs"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      bs: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$bs",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.name",
              /* Filter value */
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Solution 1 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k4EHYbdHvu_)

---

### Solution 2

Use [`$lookup` with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup).

```
db.collA.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collB",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$id",
                    "$refId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$name",
                    /* Filter value */
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "bs"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Solution 2 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oHBIpo2WeIb)

Comment: thanks! which one performs better in your opinion?

Comment: Just my personal opinion (Correct me if I'm wrong), Solution 2 may be better performance-wise, while Solution 1 is simpler for readable.